# Making one character out of array in R

Tags: arrays, r, character

I have a vector of numbers `values<-c(7,0,1.708)` that I would like to re-write as a character of length one `7:0:1.708`. 
I have tried `value<-("values[1]:values[2]:values[3]")` but that doesn't do the job and I feel like I'm missing something pretty simple.
Any help?

Comment: Try `paste(values,collapse=":")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `collapse` argument to paste:

```
paste(values, collapse=":")
[1] "7:0:1.708"
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

`paste0(values[1],":", values[2],":", values[3])`

The reason why your code here: `value <- ("values[1]:values[2]:values[3]")` do not work is because anything inserted between `""` is considered as a string which is a non-active concatenation of letters.

To concatenate strings use `paste`.